# Sitecore: Restrict language of version of an Item to only English

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2

I have multilingual website and for one particular item I want to restrict the content editor to create language versions. For this item I only want to have English version only.

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Does the content editor need access rights to add other languages elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. He can add the language version of other items. I am actually to totally ban the language version for item `A` does not matter if its content editor or any other role. I just want to totally block the language version of item `A`. Only use English version and that's all.

Comment: Any interest in hooking into the `item:addversion` event and canceling/deleting the version as it's created?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar scenario and looked into the item:addversion as Jim mentioned. However, it's quite hard to not get into a catch 22 situation when doing so. In my case I create a lot of items by code. Doing that without raising events (silent updates) is quite tricky, since it would also disable item cache clearing, indexing of the item and so on.

Instead, I opted for creating validators and gutters. I put all the logic in a class that can evaluate what languages an item is expected to be in, and made a item validator that fails if it has surplus (or missing) language versions. The validator was then added to the Global Rules. I also created a gutter that does virtually the same in order find and repair such errors more easily.

Answer (score 1):

Each Language under the **/sitecore/system/Languages** node has a **Language Read** and **Language Write** property that you can set via the **Security Editor** to restrict which roles have which permissions.

[image]

Comment: This will apply to all items, and not just a particular/subset of items.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I noticed the item part after I posted. Not 100% sure if there is a way to do this per item..

Comment: I don't think there is either, not OOTB. Sections of content you can do, but language variations... it would have to be something quite custom.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to achieve this, and without writing any coding/hacking into Sitecore would be to make the [fields shared](http://www.jasinskionline.com/technicalwiki/(S(2yjfbd45ckjpb2551ltpef55))/Unversioned-versus-Shared-Sitecore.ashx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), all of them if necessary, for the data template of item `A`.

[image]

That way it doesn't matter if another language version is added, all languages will only be able to edit the single version of the field. It will also have the advantage that when editing content in a different language the editor will be able to continue editing the fields without having to switch back to `en` first, however the disadvantage is that ALL versions will also be the same which means the item cannot be put through workflow if that is a requirement.